# how to calculate the float reminder for the two float values

Tags: objective-c, floating-point

I have two float values, 'a' and 'b' .

I need to calculate the reminder of these two float values, and it must be a float value.

Let

```
float a = 1.1;
float b = 0.5;
```

So the remainder 'r' should be accurate value

i.e.  r = a % b

r = 1.1 % 0.5

```
  0.5) 1.1 (2
       1.0
     ______

       0.1

  r = 0.1
```

**But it causes to an error invalid operand for float values.**

How to do it?

Comment: Why is this for java, c++, objective-c AND c? you using it in 4 projects?

Comment: It doesn't look like Java, since `1.1 % 0.5` is legal in Java.  (And no matter what he does, he won't get an "accurate" value.  For starters, he won't even have an accurate value for `1.1`, since `1.1` can't be represented exactly in most machine floating point.)

Comment: actually i need in objective c, what ever the language logic is same right.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C , C++  and Objective-C that would be [`fmod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/fmod/).

Answer (score 6):

use **fmod()**

```
#include <math.h>
double x,y,z;
x = 1.1;
y = 0.5;
z = fmod(x,y)
```

Don't tforget the -lm liker flag if you are on linux/unix/mac-osx/.

for more info

```
$man fmod
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out

```
float x = (float)(1.1 % 0.5);
NSLog(@"%f",x);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ranga yes of course, this will work in java also. But you cannot use fmod() in java.

Comment: % working with integers only (int)%(int) in C or C++

Answer (score 1):

did you declare it?

```
float r;
```

you have to do that before you could do any calculations

so

```
float r;

float a = 1.1;
float b = 0.5;

r = a % b;
```

Comment: In C (and C++?) it is invalid to use floating point numbers for operands of the `%` operator.